# Best image enlargement software, perhaps with with integrated ML / AI functionality in 2022?

Tags: images, image-processing, image-editor, machine-learning, image-recognition

I have some old documents and photos that have some text on diagrams that need to be enhanced. Various efforts in Adobe Photoshop 2022 have been lackluster and I was wondering if there are any solid enlargement offerings presently that have any particularly strong results for enhancing text and diagrams / line drawings that are not entirely in focus and/or are old and blurred.

Hunting about on the search engine space really just gives a bunch of crap blogs about the "top 10" or "top 5" and nothing really seems to be actually real or sincere in any of these results presently.

Has anyone had any experience with any software that really stands out for image enhancement and enlargement as explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generally-acknowledged 'best' of these is…

[OnOne Resize](https://www.on1.com/products/resize/) - available separately or as part of the PhotoRAW suite.

[Topaz Gigapixel AI](https://www.topazlabs.com/gigapixel-ai) - also available as a bundle with DeNoise & Sharpen

All the above have a free trial.

Both have always been better than Photoshop. I've used OnOne for years, through many incarnations. I periodically test Topaz, but I've never been convinced it's sufficiently better that I need to buy both.
OnOne was always faster than Topaz & for a long time the clear 'winner' for quality - but this was in pre "AI" days. I haven't tried the Topaz in quite a while so idk what improvements they've made. Last time I tried it, it felt too slow. Results were always good, though.

Having said all that - I've never tried it on photos of documents. You might be better with an OCR suite for that.

Comment: Yeah, in my case I have a photo that needs to be enlarged before it can be processed by OCR. I just see no way wherewith when a human can't read the text that OCR will be able to go any further without an enormous amount of ML training... Gigapixel's trial has done fair, but not good enough. I suppose I'll try OnOne's version since I had already been using Gigapixel without a lot of success... Appreciate the tip.